# SOAP namespace change axis

Tags: web-services, soapui

I want to host a web-service which will return a response of

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <QcB2BQNBPaymentIntegrationBalUpdatePaymentPostingResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
         <response xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <b:string>QCP-0031312;158155421123</b:string>
         </response>
      </QcB2BQNBPaymentIntegrationBalUpdatePaymentPostingResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

but I am getting the response as

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <QcB2BQNBPaymentIntegrationBalUpdatePaymentPostingResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
         <response >
            <ns1:string xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">QCP-0031312;158155421123</ns1:string>
         </response>
      </QcB2BQNBPaymentIntegrationBalUpdatePaymentPostingResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to get the former response. please share some insight.

note: I've generated the java bean skeleton using axis